# When it is better to truncate and insert all data then update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scheduler to a service to get help data(about 15 000) for every 30 mitues.

What practice is better ?

1. To truncate db and insert all every time

or

2. To create a 3 collection (insert, update and delete) and in post-processing to update these help data by necessity

Comment: Why are you truncating in the first place? Does the extant data in the table have any value or not?

Comment: @Dai Currently not. But after first iteration 15 000 objects is gonna be inserted regardless of implementation selection

Comment: Are there any Foreign Keys involved? Triggers?

Comment: @wildplasser No, it does not have any foreign key

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on the indexes, number of update or delete needed. Number of columns of the table could be in play along with normally how many columns to be updated.

But since there are 15000 rows. I would go for truncate and insert.

Comment: Can u please clarify, why u would prefer to go for trucate and insert for 15 000 rows ? If there would be 100 000 rows, would u go for "updating" data ? If so, why ? delete operation is the most costly ?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier we need to know many factors. For example if there are 100000 rows and there are chance to be updated only couple of hundred then it should be faster to delete and rei-insert  those instead of truncate and insert all.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `insert`s are faster than `update`s and `delete`s because new records can just be added "at the end of the table", which minimizes locking.  Of course, this can be altered by the presence of indexes and triggers.

That suggests that the solution just doing inserts sounds better.

However, the two are not the same.  If you truncate and `insert`, then all the data is only new data.  If you `insert`/`update`/`delete`, then you will have a mixture of old and new data.

So, if you want only clean data, use `insert`.  If you want "progressive" data, then modify as you go.